# Where has module-specified HOOK_preprocess_page gone in D8?

Tags: 8

I'm making a quick module whilst playing with D8, which I want to preprocess Stylus into CSS. The obvious choice for me, coming from D7, would be to use `hook_preprocess_page`, but it seems to have been removed from D8, or at least only in themes and not modules.

So just to reiterate, I have my module `stylus`, my file `stylus.module` and the function `stylus_preprocess_page(&$variables)`, but no dice.

What would be the best D8 alternative?

Answer (score 2):

This hook has not been removed, there are still preprocess hooks for modules:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x

Comment: Aaaagh, it's because I hadn't cleared the caches. Well, I did clear caches but used `drush cc all` rather than `drush cr` so nothing happened. Rookie mistake. Whoops!